# temperature gauge on my Ford Focus keeps dropping to 1/4 when temperatures outside at below freezing

Tags: ford, cooling-system, focus

I have had my car into a mechanics shop under warranty numerous times over a 3 week span. My first initial problem was that my temperature gauge went from sitting in the normal spot (half way on the gauge) to below a quarter when I turned my heat on in the car. I took it in for inspection and was told “that is normal for the temperature gauge to do that.” The following day the temperature was -20 degrees Celsius outside and it did the same thing only this time it was blowing cold air in my face. I have had 4 cars now and not one of them has had this issue therefore I do not believe this is normal to happen. I took it back in and I was right when I told them it was my thermostat. They then informed me it was stuck wide open and they replaced the thermostat. The next day I had heat blowing out of the car but my temperature gauge is still dropping down almost to the cold mark (just below 1/4)...   I took the car back to the shop to which they proceeded to go over the car again to which I was told there was a blockage in the heating core. They completed a flush to remove the blockage and told me if it did not work they would replace the part. I called the following day as it did not stop my temperature gauge from dropping. They informed me the car was functioning normally and there was nothing they could do as I had heat to my car. 
My husband is a mechanic and has also told me this is not normal for my car to be doing this but the ford location I have been working with does not seem to want to help me with this issue. 
I was in a hospital for a whole day as I fell sick on Friday... I left the hospital in -15 weather. With the fan for my heat turned off it too 20 minutes to warm to 1/2 way mark on the gauge. As soon as I turned my heat on in the car the temperature gauge again began to drop to just below 1/4. This time when I arrived home I placed my hand over the top of the dash where the heat was directed to come out and I was getting very minimal heat to the point it felt cold. 
I am getting frustrated with the whole process and I’m trying to figure out what could be happening with my car /temperature gauge that would be causing this to still happen. 
I am looking for someone who is actually able to give me an idea of what could be going on with my vehicle as I need to call them back on Tuesday with a complaint.

Is there a list of things anyone can provide me that may tell me what the issue is with this car?

I already have:
Thermostat.  (Already replaced once)
Heating core (flushed once)
Temperature gauge failure....

Are there any sensors, valves, or other issues this could be caused by?

Thank you,

Donna Grant
NS, Canada

Comment: Have you performed a hydrometer test on your coolant's reservoir? What temperature is it rated at? Remember, minus 15°C when parked is minus 30°C at 50kph. Diesel's (which typically generate less heat from the engine) will block some or all of the forward radiator area so less heat is lost. Is your fan running all the time? An electric fan shouldn't be.